# Hadoop 1.0.1 ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, hadoop

I run a program on hadoop 1.0.1 and I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: -i
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:149)
```

I mention the fact that the same code works on hadoop 1.2.1 but on hadoop 1.0.1 doesn't.

```
This is my main class:
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            readArguments(args);
        JobConf conf = new JobConf(Embed.class);
        conf.setJobName("embed");

        conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

        conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        //conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
        conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

        conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
        conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(input));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(output));

        JobClient.runJob(conf);

    }
```

The mapper and reducer signature classes are:

```
public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable> {
     public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, LongWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
          ........
     }
}

public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, LongWritable, Text, LongWritable> {
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<LongWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, LongWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
               ..........
        }
```

Any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: Can you show the "hadoop jar" command which you use.

Comment: Exactly, "-i" in "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: -i" does not look like a class name. What command are you executing?

Comment: bin/hadoop jar embed.jar Embed -i input -o output_emb

Comment: Are you sure that's exactly what you run? it sounds like you are actually missing Embed or there is a missing space

Comment: I was actually missing Embed, it works now thanks very much.